# How to perform n effective JOIN operation?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a table with data like:

**tagmap**

```
===============
 item | tagid
---------------
 1111 |   101
 1111 |   102
 2222 |   101
 2222 |   103
 3333 |   104
 4444 |   105
 4444 |   106
 5555 |   101
 5555 |   103
==============
```

item + tagid = composite primary key

I have a MySQL query like;

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(a.tagid ORDER BY a.tagid) tags
  FROM tagmap a
  JOIN tagmap b
    ON b.item = a.item
   AND b.tagid <= a.tagid
 WHERE b.tagid = '101'
 GROUP
    BY a.item;
```

Which returns;

```
101,102
101,103
```

These are unique possible combinations in which `101` is available.

`tagid`s are unique ids of some flavors. I have another table like;

**flavors**

```
===============
 id  | flavor
---------------
 101 | flavorA
 102 | flavorB
 103 | flavorC
 104 | flavorD
 105 | flavorE
 106 | flavorF
===============
```

id = primary key

Instead of my previous MySQL result, what I want is;

```
flavorA,flavorB
flavorA,flavorC
```

upto my logic, I need to perform an `INNER JOIN`. But `flavors` table may contain 500K+ entries, and `tagmap` table will be minimum 2 times bigger than `flavors` table. Thus its quite not-so-easy to perform a join operation. But I think, if I can generate a table like;

```
===============
 item | tagid
---------------
 1111 |   101
 1111 |   102
 2222 |   101
 2222 |   103
==============
```

Then I can Join this table with `flavors` table, which may (I think) be an easier join than the previous join operation. I think this is possible with something like nested queries.

Is there any way I can achieve this? Is `INNER JOIN` the only possible solution? If so, then how can I perform an `INNER JOIN` in my query? I use PHP+MySQL.

Comment: Don't GROUP_CONCAT the result. It just makes it harder to manage in PHP.

Comment: @Strawberry . Alright. Do you have any suggestion to achieve my result in some effective way?

Comment: @Strawberry if I remove `GROUP_CONCAT` I get no result..

Comment: duplicate of your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016982

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any other better option than MySQL INNER JOIN, to join a tag-mapping table with tag-name table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016982/is-there-any-other-better-option-than-mysql-inner-join-to-join-a-tag-mapping-ta)

Comment: @Drew I want to know how to perform an inner join in my query. I donno how to perform inner join in the given query

Comment: can you provide a sqlfiddle. We will bang one out. I know your tables are trivial in concept, but it helps to save us time because we review skads of questions. Thanks

Comment: also, as you were concerned about performance, showing the results of `show create table tagmap` would be helpful to view indexes. Ah, never mind, you mention the composite

Comment: But nice research on your end, and supporting your question. I would just try to avoid dupes. Maybe delete the other one if it has low use Answers on it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you need the self-join.

Your first query can be

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(a.tagid ORDER BY a.tagid) tags
  FROM tagmap a
 WHERE a.item IN (SELECT item from tagmap WHERE tagid = 101)
 GROUP BY a.item
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The complexity of this query and yours are probably about the same.

Once you've got that working, you can substitute the flavor names for tie id values very simply like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(b.flavor ORDER BY a.tagid) tags
  FROM tagmap a
  JOIN flavors b ON a.tagid = b.id
 WHERE a.item IN (SELECT item from tagmap WHERE tagid = 101)
 GROUP BY a.item
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I would put together a SQLFiddle for you, but it isn't working right now.

(`JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` are the same thing.)

Comment: @Strawberry really dislikes `GROUP_CONCAT()`. It has its limitations, but it also has a bit of power.

Comment: you were almost going to go wiki answer on that, weren't you :P

Comment: @OllieJones this too return `id`s, not names. I mean, it returns `101,102` instead of `flavorA,flavorB`

Comment: Strange. I actually tried the query, and it worked for me. Double check that you actually typed `GROUP_CONCAT(b.flavor ORDER BY a.tagid)` and not something else.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe I'm missing something but wouldn't this query give you the result you want?

```
SELECT tagmap.item, flavors.flavor
  FROM tagmap
  JOIN flavors
  ON tagmap.tagid = flavor.id;
```

This will join your items to each of their flavors where the tagid matches the flavor id resulting in:

```
===============
 item | flavor
---------------
 1111 |   flavorA
 1111 |   flavorB
 2222 |   flavorA
 2222 |   flavorC
==============
```

Using this query as a jumping off point, you can now expiremnt with `group_concat` to format the results. Alternatively, you can group the results by looping through them in php. Quick example:

```
$my_array = [];
while ($data = $rows->fetch_assoc())
{
    //initalize the item if it doesn't exist yet
    if(!isset($my_array[$data['item']) {
        $my_array[$data['item']] = [];
    }
    //add the flavor to the time
    $my_array[$data['item'][] = $data['flavor'];
}

echo $json_encode($my_array);
```

results: `{1111:["flavorA", "flavorB"], 2222:...`

Hope that helps.